# Copying Magento 1.9 product to Magento 2.1.3 using CSV

Tags: import, product, magento2

I am trying to copy the products from magento 1.9 to magento 2.1.3 using CSV.
when i import the CSV in magento 2.1.3 it show error
i want to know about the actual way for importing the products from magento 1.9 CSV to magento 2.1.3